# Absolute Bottom Outside of Relative Div in Middle of Page

Tags: css, absolute

I've searched and tried multiple fixes (most of which I found on stack overflow, and some from other sites like CSS Tricks and matthewjamestaylor.com), but nothing has worked for me. (Fixed position works, but is not an option.) I need the footer to stay at the bottom, but right now it's in the middle.

At this stage I'm assuming that something in my coding is working against me, but I've also tried removing styles/divs and it still has me puzzled. Perhaps I just need a fresh perspective.

[The JSFiddle code is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/D4nk6/)
[The FULL JSFiddle code is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Puz86/) (If anyone needs it)

Thanks in advance!

`#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    height: 130px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 20px 20px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 20px 20px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
     box-shadow: inset 0 20px 20px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
     font: bold 18px/1.2em sans-serif;
     z-index: 400;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
     background-attachment: fixed;
     background-image: url(http://informationsecured.com/chapelhill/images/background-green.jpg);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center top;}`

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Hah, sorry; need the footer to stay at bottom.

Comment: Also, when making jsFiddles for SO, try to attach only the bare minimum of code required to demonstrate your problem. Ain't nobody got time to find the relevant lines if you have 1000 lines of unrelated code...

Comment: Do you want your footer to always stay at the bottom..i.e always visible or do you want it at the bottom when you scroll to the bottom?

Comment: Do not want a fixed footer; must be visible at bottom when scrolled.

Comment: Here You Go - http://jsfiddle.net/D4nk6/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a lot of absolute positions for layouting is generally a bad idea. You lose the chance of letting the browser do the heavy lifting concerning element heights in relation to their content.

To get your #footer to stay at the bottom, there are a few things we need to do:

- `body` shouldn't have `height: 100%;`. Otherwise every element relatively positioned to bottom will be positioned in relation to the height of the visible content of the browser window (looks like `position: fixed;`, until you scroll and then the element moves along with the content).
- `#wrapper` shouldn't have `position: absolute;`. We don't know it's final height, so it's better to leave it relative, to aid positioning the footer right underneath it.

As a general guideline; if you're calculating pixel value offsets to keep elements from going on top of each other, you're probably doing something wrong.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D4nk6/2/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm most definitely still learning so your explination is super helpful, and I'll keep it on mind for future build out.

Answer (score 0):

Position:fixed is the right solution for this (I am assuming you mean for an always-visible footer).  Is there any reason why you can't use that?

If you really can't, then I'm pretty sure javascript would be required.

Comment: Client is calling the shots and absolutely does not want a fixed footer.

As much as I'd love to stick with pure CSS, if JS is the only way…I'll do it.

Comment: Sorry - just seen your comment above about wanting it to appear after scrolling.  I still think js would be your only solution - put the footer outside the rest of the content, and make the main content's minimum height the window height minus the footer height.

However, if the footer is just an image then that could be pure css - set it as a background image on the body of the page, and add some padding so no other content goes over the top.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Richard; seems like I was working against the code with some unnecessary position:absolutes. Now that they've been cleaned up it seems that the code is working the way it should. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

There has been one hell of a site I always use for sticking the footer to the bottom. It gives you all the duct-tape you need too!

http://cssstickyfooter.com/

Their site has the relevant information about this. I'm not attaching the code, as this question has been asked way too many times on SO, and I think there is enough resources online for these things.

Comment: Thanks for the link; I actually did use that to try and figure out my issue, but it didn't work for me. However, it also looks like I was working against myself with some unnecessary code, so who knows, might work now. ^^;